# CloudFormation CreateStack API Failing if it contains Macro

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am using CloudFormation Boto3 APIs to create stack using [createStack](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.create_stack) API. I am able to create stack if I pass a template which does not have a macro.

Ex -

```
Resources:
  Bucket1:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  Bucket2:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
```

I have also created a macro which I am able to invoke through CLI and through CloudFormation UI. So basically I am using the above cloud-formation with added transform.

```
Transform: StackMetrics

Resources:
  Bucket1:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  Bucket2:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
```

So as mentioned earlier it is working through CLI and UI, but not through API.

```
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
response = client.create_stack(
        StackName='MacroTestStack', TemplateURL='<path_to_above_template>',
        Capabilities=['CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND']
    )

return response
```

I tried using CLI and UI.

Answer (score 1):

If it works in the CLI and in the UI then it works in the API (the API being the underlying AWS API). I think you mean that it isn't working in the boto3 SDK (note SDK, not API, these are quite different things).

The most likely reason for this is that your boto3 SDK is back-level. Update it and retry.

PS if you make an SDK call and it doesn't work, usually there will be some kind of error message, error response code, or exception. Please provide that information so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. I figured out the issue. It seems we had to give - RoleARN. According to documentation - If you don't specify a value, AWS CloudFormation uses the role that was previously associated with the stack. If no role is available, AWS CloudFormation uses a temporary session that is generated from your user credentials. So I had to explicitly give a role which CloudFormation will assume while creating stack. In case of macro this role should have lambda invoke permission. So I added a role with this permission and it got working. Anyway the CF error messages are not very useful.

Comment: Something here doesn’t quite add up. Your code is calling create_stack so there is no “role that was previously associated with the stack”. And, fundamentally, using the awscli should be the same as using boto3, so if you were invoking the same APIs with the same credentials, then the result would be the same. Anyhow, glad you have resolved the issue.